# Is there a way to fully encapsulate React from the Window object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I do not think this is possible, but I just want to be sure. I want to use react in order to build widgets that will used on client websites. When I saw that the react library was only 5Kb then I thought of using it.

Still do, but because of various reasons I can't simply use react to build the widgets. One of the main reasons is that I want to use lazy-loading to load in missing peaces of the widgets and it is more than likely that multiple widgets from us will be on the same website so I do not want to load React multiple times.

Now I know I can use [browserify](https://benclinkinbeard.com/posts/how-browserify-works/) to isolate react from the client's website, but I am not sure on that. If all else fails we can simply load the hole application (after being tans-compiled with browserify) and drop the lazy-load aspect, but that is not something I want and not something that is required from me. The specs say quite specifically that lazy-loading needs to be used... if not in so specific words.

So yeah... maybe I am missing something. Is there a way to isolate the React base library in ES5 or ES6 (our browser support is IE9+)? Right now from what I've seen it is not possible, but again maybe I am missing something big? Though I am willing to consider browserify to do it.

PS. If the answer is no, then please give a reasoning as to why so I can accept the answer.

Comment: "I do not want to load React multiple times" If you load it once, if adding the script multiple times it will be loaded from browser cache, it is not that it will be actually requested.

Comment: Are the widgets isolated HTML pages, or are they fragments of HTML and Javascript loaded as part of the outer page's document model?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- the multiple requests is not really the problem, but is the fact that when browserify transcompiles the code, its made into one file... so I am not sure how to even make sure that the code won't be repeated. The problem is not with the same widget, but with 2 distinct widgets with their own independent code base

Comment: @Gonzalo.- that depends on if the HTTP headers that the server sending the script provides in the response support caching resources, and that also doesn't solve the issue of conflicting React instances in the same execution context, even if you do load from cache.

Comment: @cbp hmm... basically both I guess... on one side they are isolated  HTML pages, but because I want to share the React and other parts between the widgets... then I guess you can say they are fragments, but perhaps I do not quite get the question.

Comment: Although react should work on IE9 with polyfills, I won‘t recommend it. Even with IE11 we sometimes run into heavy issues. But it‘s mostly on us as we did not optimize a lot for IE. On the other side: if all your widgets run on the same stack you could use webpack to put all node_modules in its own vendor.js file which you could always include on the website.

Answer (score 1):

You could use use [browserifies externals & excludes](https://github.com/browserify/browserify/blob/master/readme.markdown#multiple-bundles) to build multiple different bundles. Lets say you got `widgetA.js` and `widgetB.js` and both `require("react")` then you could do:

```
 $ browserify -r react > static/react.js
 $ browserify -x react widgetA.js > static/widgetA.js
 $ browserify -x react widgetB.js > static/widgetB.js
```

Now inside the page were widgetA is needed, add both react and the widget:

```
 <script defer src="./static/react.js" ></script>
 <script defer src="./static/widgetA.js" ></script>
```

Then `react.js` gets cached and won't be reloaded on other pages, this is a "build only" solution so it works across browsers (if the code itself works there).

Comment: this is exactly what I was planning to do if all else failed, but its nice to have it here for those that did not get what I meant under "isolate react with browserify"